# jQuery Previous button not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

probably me being very silly after a long day, I can get my next anchor to work to take me to the next section on click but by previous anchor just takes me back to the top.

My code is:

```js
// scroll next section

$('.charityhub-next').click(function() {
  var next = $('.fundraising-ideas');
  $(".fundraising-ideas").each(function(i, element) {
    next = $(element).offset().top;
    if (next - 10 > $(document).scrollTop()) {
      return false; // break
    }
  });
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: next
  }, 700);
});


// scroll prev section

$('.charityhub-prev').click(function() {
  var prev = $('section');

  $(".fundraising-ideas").each(function(i, element) {
    prev = $(element).offset().top;
    if (prev + 10 < $(document).scrollTop()) {
      return false; // break
    }
  });
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: prev
  }, 700);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="charity-hub-nav">
  <ul class="container">
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="charityhub-prev"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>Previous Section</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class='charity-hub-sections'>Show Sections <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="charityhub-next">Next Section <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<section class="fundraising-ideas">
  <h1>Some Heading</h1>
  <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour.</p>
  <div class="idea-section">
    <h2>Second heading</h2>
    <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum,
      you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. </p>
    <img src="" alt="">
    <button>Get more info</button>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="fundraising-ideas">
  <h1>Some Heading</h1>
  <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour.</p>
  <div class="idea-section">
    <h2>Second heading</h2>
    <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum,
      you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. </p>
    <img src="" alt="">
    <button>Get more info</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

basically i just need the previous button going to the previous section, not all the way to the top

Many thanks

Comment: Have you tried debugging to check if it jumps into the `return false` case?

Comment: If I'm reading the logic correctly, the issue seems to be related to you're trying to check all the previous sections to see which one is less than the scroll amount, but you're starting at the first one.  So if you are on the 5th one, and you check the 1st one first, rather than the 4th one, of course that first one will be less than the scroll amount

Comment: A simpler way to do things like this is to add a class to the current element. Then you can use `.next()` and `.previous()` to get the next or previous element, rather than looping through all the sections.

Comment: So continuing from what @Taplar said, you need to do the check in the reverse order for the Previous button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.  The intention is to try to find all the elements whose offset it above the current scroll amount.  Once you have that list, grabbing the last one should get the previous one to the visible one.

```
$('.charityhub-prev').click(function() {
  var prev = $(".fundraising-ideas").filter(function(i, element) {
    return $(element).offset().top + 10 < $(document).scrollTop();
  }).last().offset().top;

  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: prev
  }, 700);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, its been a long day coding, I agree that .next() & .previous() is a lot simpler. I will try to incorporate this tomorrow on a clearer mind but once again thank you!